# How to set focus to the text after the hint in EditText?

Tags: java, android, input, focus, android-edittext

I'm interested in you can set the focus to the text after the prompt to EditText? If no such attribute for xml layout? At the moent I still looked like this.

[image]

need

[image]

**EDIT :**
**The fastest and working answer given *Asok*

I also found a similar way:

*EditText.append("60"); // 60 or your text in EditText***

Comment: @DeepankerChaudhary ?? I don't think you understand the question. I believe the OP is asking how to place the cursor behind the hint text

Comment: Siruk, Based on your Edit above I just wanted to make sure you understood `append`. If you use `EditText.append` the text gets inserted at the end of the `EditText`, `setText` replaces all text within the `EditText`. i.e. if you ran `EditText.append("60");` twice in your code then your field would read `6060`

Comment: @Asok: I understand, and so do not call setText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are looking to place the cursor behind the hint text, if this is correct then it is not possible, you'll have to remove hint and use `setText` instead, like so:

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sixtyseconds);
et.setText("60");
et.setSelection(et.getText().length());
```

Answer (score 3):

A hint is no real text, it disappears after the user types something. Assuming the cursor would be at the end of the hint what behaviour would you expect when the user presses a button and the hint disappears?

What you can do is set a default text in the XML via

```
android:text="60"
```

or in code via

```
editText.setText("60");
```

and on focus jump to the end of the EditText via

```
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
```