# How to move the cursor without moving the hint in material edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor-position

I have such a material field [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zo20.png) , but i need to replace cursor like this  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alo7L.png) without replacing hint

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorTextGray"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled = "true"
        app:passwordToggleTint="@color/color_ic_visibility"
        app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/ic_visibility">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorNotSelected"
            android:hint="Пароль"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextGray"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding android:paddingStart to editText?

Comment: Yeah. But after that floating label moves too. I need to replace only cursor

Answer (score 2):

You can move the cursor to a desired position using Java. In your `Activity` you could try this method:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
editText.setSelection(//position);
```

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html#setSelection(android.text.Spannable, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html#setSelection(android.text.Spannable,%20int))

However this will not work using a hint only, because the `EditText` needs content. You can workaround this by creating your own hint using this code:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
editText.setText("Пароль");
editText.setSelection(3); // for example 3
```

Reference: [How to set focus to the text after the hint in EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271957/how-to-set-focus-to-the-text-after-the-hint-in-edittext)

Comment: i has empty edittext. I need to override start cursor position. After adding padding floating label is moving too.

Comment: You can't dot that by only using the hint. You can workaround this by using updated answer.

Comment: no. I need to move without entering any text. The text should start right from the beginning of 40dp

Comment: Then use `android:paddingLeft="10dp"`

Comment: But after that floating label moves too.

Comment: Did u put it in EditText or TextInputLayout, must be in EditText